# 401 Unauthorized Access while using Twilio's Programmable Chat

Tags: ios, swift, chat, twilio

I am trying to create an iOS chat application using Twilio's Programmable Chat.
I am able to retrieve the token from Twilio by passing device token and identity, but I am getting the **401 unauthorized Access** while loading the channels(if any). I have checked my Twilio credentials

```
TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID 
TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN 
TWILIO_API_KEY
TWILIO_API_SECRET 
TWILIO_IPM_SERVICE_SID
```

and all of them are assigned properly.

This is my response which I received from Twilio.

json = ["identity": ved, "token": **eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsImN0eSI6InR3aWxpby1mcGE7dj0xIn0.eyJqdGkiOiJkNTNmZGFjZDlmMWUwODA0OGZjOGE3MDU5ZTAyYTg1Zi0xNDk4NjY5Mjc1IiwiZ3JhbnRzIjp7ImlkZW50aXR5IjoidmVkIiwiaXBfbWVzc2FnaW5nIjp7InNlcnZpY2Vfc2lkIjoiSVMwNjYxMWUwNzE4M2U0NmVkOWE5ZWM1Yzg4ZGFhZmViNCIsImVuZHBvaW50X2lkIjoiQ2hhdFNlcnZpY2U6dmVkOnVuZGVmaW5lZCJ9fSwiaWF0IjoxNDk4NjY5Mjc1LCJleHAiOjE0OTg2NzI4NzUsImlzcyI6ImQ1M2ZkYWNkOWYxZTA4MDQ4ZmM4YTcwNTllMDJhODVmIiwic3ViIjoiQUMwYjI4OWViMGUwNTc2ZGU0NDNhMTkzYzdkZjk4YTg4OCJ9.LfSUM3v70Am3d3me6BQn7NC3T6mPggD9cikjf52Qvk8**]

For reference, I am getting the below stackTrace in the console.

2017-06-28 22:33:18.705 twiliochat[1252:52536] TNNotificationClient[2]:     0x7000047ea000 | 06/28/22:33:18.704 | WARNING  | 7      | TNNotificationClient | onTwilsockError: 0 - **Poco exception while connecting: I/O error: Bad socket descriptor**

2017-06-28 22:34:07.682 twiliochat[1252:52530] TNTransportConnectingState[3]:     0x7000044d8000 | 06/28/22:34:07.680 | INFO     | 9      | TNTransportConnectingState | Leaving state: Transport connecting
2017-06-28 22:34:07.682 twiliochat[1252:53398] TNTwilsockClient[4]:     0x700004143000 | 06/28/22:34:07.680 | DEBUG    | 1      | TNTwilsockClient | onMessageReceived (226)
TWILSOCK V1.0 160
**{"method":"close","id":"TM43a26b096fb040dca4751bef7ca17dec","payload_size":43,"payload_type":"application/json","status":{"code":401,"status":"Not authorized"}}
{"code":401,"status":"Authorization error"}**

Few Notes to consider before answering this thread :

1. I have set up my server properly and I am doing ngrok also.
2. I am using node.js for server setup.

Comment: Can you post an example token that I can take a look at?

Comment: This is the response I got :

Comment: json = ["identity": ved, "token": eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsImN0eSI6InR3aWxpby1mcGE7dj0xIn0.eyJqdGkiOiJkNTNmZGFjZDlmMWUwODA0OGZjOGE3MDU5ZTAyYTg1Zi0xNDk4NjY5Mjc1IiwiZ3JhbnRzIjp7ImlkZW50aXR5IjoidmVkIiwiaXBfbWVzc2FnaW5nIjp7InNlcnZpY2Vfc2lkIjoiSVMwNjYxMWUwNzE4M2U0NmVkOWE5ZWM1Yzg4ZGFhZmViNCIsImVuZHBvaW50X2lkIjoiQ2hhdFNlcnZpY2U6dmVkOnVuZGVmaW5lZCJ9fSwiaWF0IjoxNDk4NjY5Mjc1LCJleHAiOjE0OTg2NzI4NzUsImlzcyI6ImQ1M2ZkYWNkOWYxZTA4MDQ

Comment: I am posting my console logs also for your reference

Comment: TNTransportConnectingState[3]:     0x7000044d8000 | 06/28/22:34:07.680 | INFO     | 9      | TNTransportConnectingState | Leaving state: Transport connecting
2017-06-28 22:34:07.682 twiliochat[1252:53398] TNTwilsockClient[4]:     0x700004143000 | 06/28/22:34:07.680 | DEBUG    | 1      | TNTwilsockClient | onMessageReceived (226)
TWILSOCK V1.0 160
{"method":"close","id":"TM43a26b096fb040dca4751bef7ca17dec","payload_size":43,"payload_type":"application/json","status":{"code":401,"status":"Not authorized"}}
{"code":401,"status":"Authorization error"}

Comment: I think your token got cut off, could you maybe edit your question and add the token. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

It looks like you are using your auth token instead of your API Key when generating your access token.

Make sure you are instantiating the Access Token like this:

```
  const accessToken = new AccessToken(
    context.TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID,
    context.TWILIO_API_KEY,
    context.TWILIO_API_SECRET
  );
```

The API Key should start "SK..."

Just as a precaution, since your auth token has been exposed you should change that in your Twilio console.

Let me know if that helps at all.

Comment: Got it. Thanks Phil.

Comment: If this works and you now have access to the API, could you mark the answer as correct, please?

Comment: Hey @philnash, I am trying to implement twilio chat in my app. I have generated the access token but I dont know how to start implementation as there is no tutorials. Can you please help me with the chat implementation.

Comment: @S.S.D [Here's a tutorial](https://www.twilio.com/docs/chat/tutorials/chat-application-ios-swift) and a [quick start application](https://www.twilio.com/docs/chat/ios/quickstart) that I recommend you read through to understand. Then, if you have specific problems, please ask a question here on Stack Overflow.